# Unexpected HAPROXY acl behaviour tcp payload routing

Tags: tcp, routes, acl, backend, haproxy

I am setting up simple tcp connection routing using HAProxy acl's. The idea is to route connections depending on request content having two flavors: read and write requests.

For testing I made a simple tcp client/server setup using perl. Strangely enough about 10-40% of the ACL's fail and are sent to the default backend.

The ACL's should find the substring 'read' or 'write' and route accordingly, but this is not allways the case.

Sending a read/write request using nc (netcat) has the same effect.

I tested this configuration with mode=http and everything works as expected.

I also tested with reg, sub and bin, to no avail.

The example server setup is as follows:

- HAProxy instance, listens on port 8000
- Client (creates tcp connection to proxy and sends user input (read/write string) to server through port 8000, after which it closes the connection)
- Server1 (write server), listens on port 8001
- Server2 (read server), listens on port 8002
- Server3 (default server), listens on port 8003

My HAProxy configuration file looks is:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0 debug
    #daemon
    maxconn 32

defaults
    log global
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend tcp-in
    bind *:8000
    tcp-request inspect-delay 3s

    acl read req.payload(0,4) -m sub read
    acl write req.payload(0,5) -m sub write

    use_backend read_servers if read
    use_backend write_server if write

    default_backend testFault

backend write_server
    server server1 127.0.0.1:8001 maxconn 32
backend read_servers
    server server2 127.0.0.1:8002 maxconn 32
backend testFault
    server server3 127.0.0.1:8003 maxconn 32
```

The client code (in perl):

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
# auto-flush on socket
#$| = 1;

print "connecting to the server\n";

while(<STDIN>){

# create a connecting socket
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
PeerHost => 'localhost',
PeerPort => '8000',
Proto => 'tcp',
);

die "cannot connect to the server $!\n" unless $socket;

    # data to send to a server
    $req = $_;
    chomp $req;

    $size = $socket->send($req);
    print "sent data of length $size\n";

    # notify server that request has been sent
    shutdown($socket, 1);

    # receive a response of up to 1024 characters from server
    $response = "";
    $socket->recv($response, 1024);
    print "received response: $response\n";
    $socket->close();
    }
```

The server (perl code):

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
if(!$ARGV[0]){
    die("Usage; specify a port..");
}
# auto-flush on socket
$| = 1;

# creating a listening socket

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
LocalPort => $ARGV[0],
Proto => 'tcp',
Listen => 5,
Reuse => 0
);

die "cannot create socket $!\n" unless $socket;
print "server waiting for client connection on port $ARGV[0]\n";

while(1){

# waiting for a new client connection
my $client_socket = $socket->accept();

# get information about a newly connected client
my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
print "connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";

# read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
my $data = "";
$client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
print "received data: $data\n";
# write response data to the connected client
$data = "ok";
$client_socket->send($data);

# notify client that response has been sent
shutdown($client_socket, 1);
$client_socket->close();
print "Connection closed..\n\n";
}

$socket->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Binary data in haproxy is tricky. Probably some bug, but the following worked for me on haproxy 1.7.9.

I am trying to build a thrift proxy server which can route to appropriate backend based on the user_id in the payload.

```
frontend thriftrouter
  bind *:10090
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  log global
  log-format "%ci:%cp [%t] %ft %b/%s %Tw/%Tc/%Tt %B %ts %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq captured_user:%[capture.req.hdr(0)] req.len:%[capture.req.hdr(1)]"
  tcp-request inspect-delay 100ms

  tcp-request content capture req.payload(52,10) len 10
  tcp-request content capture req.len len 10
  tcp-request content accept if WAIT_END

  acl acl_thrift_call    req.payload(2,2)  -m bin 0001          # Thrift CALL method
  acl acl_magic_field_id req.payload(30,2) -m bin 270f          # Magic field number 9999

  # Define access control list for each user
  acl acl_user_u1 req.payload(52,10) -m sub |user1|
  acl acl_user_u2 req.payload(52,10) -m sub |user2|

  # Route based on the user. No default backend so that one always has to set it
  use_backend backend_1 if acl_user_u1 acl_magic_field_id acl_thrift_call
  use_backend backend_2 if acl_user_u2 acl_magic_field_id acl_thrift_call
```

When matching binary data in acl, make sure you're looking at the right number of bytes, for substring to work properly. Or use the hex conversion method and match on hex bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont I feel silly. Re-reading the HAProxy documentation I found the following directive (fetch method) that fixes the issue:

```
tcp-request content accept if WAIT_END
```

That solved the unexpected behaviour.